# projectile grep file filter

Tags: helm, projectile, grep

I'm trying to use **helm-projectile-grep** function on Windows 7, but it searches in every file, though in **.projectile** I excluded file types which I don't want to work with. Do I have to configure **grep** separately and how to do this? May be I should put something in pattern for **grep**? Thanks for advice.

Comment: `projectile-grep` takes account of excluded file types in `.projectile`, while `helm-projectile-grep` doesn't, actually `helm-projectile-grep` doesn't have the capability to ignore certain file types at all. And you can't configure `grep`, there is no `.greprc` or `.grepignore` for grep. You also can't exclude certain file types in `helm-projectile-grep`'s search pattern, it is not supported since it's hard to implement and doesn't worth.

Comment: As I see projectile-grep working exactly the same and it doesn't exclude file types. E.g. in my .projectile file I have a string "-*.lst" and by idea these files should be excluded from grep, but not it's still giving me results from these files

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment is totally wrong: both `projectile-grep` and `helm-projectile-grep` should take account of `.projectile`, however, `-/*.lst` should work instead of `-*.lst`, I don't really understand related documentation of projectile.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks a lot. If you put it for answer I'll mark it. Shame there is a mistake in official documentation.